# Count of Child Objects & Update it Grand Parent Field

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

We have 3 objects Obj A,Obj B & Obj C. Obj C has Master Detail Relationship with Obj B & Obj B has Master Detail Relationship with obj A.

**Obj A is the Grand Parent Object of Obj C.**

What I want is to get the Count of Obj C records and display the count on Grand Parent Obj A.

Problem is I can not solve this requirement by writing an apex code as all of these 3 objects are Managed Package Custom object and I don't have access of their apex classes & Triggers.

I tried to write Process Builder but can not Use Count Function.

Can someone please tell me how can I get the count using config way or best way?

**Screenshot during discussion:**

**Details on Parent Record:**
[image]

**Count Displayed:** 
[image]

**Rollup summery on Obj B:**

[image]

**Rollup Summery on Obj A:**

[image]

Comment: Why dont you make your own apex classes/triggers to do calculations?

Comment: are u talking about creating an apex class using @invocable method and call it in process builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing following steps

1. create a rollup-summary field on `obj B` and Count `Obj C` records
2. create another rollup-summary field on `Obj A` and **sum** `Obj B` field you created in step 1.
3. Put that field you created on `Obj A` in step - 2

### Example (Account > Opportunity > Opportunity Product )

> **Opportunity to Opportunity Product rollup**
>   [image]
>
> **Account to Opportunity rollup**
>   [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71244/discussion-on-answer-by-mahmood-count-of-child-objects-update-it-grand-parent).